# How can I keep a firebase function open when it's in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a file called db.js from which I make all my firebase calls.

I am calling a function in db.js from another file called home.js
How do I make it that the firebase connection stays open and the data gets passed back to home.js? I can't use a promise because that closes the connection.

Here is the function from db.js:

```
export function getShopNames() {
    let userID = auth.currentUser.uid
    let stores = []
    userDB.ref('/users/' + userID + "/stores").on('value', snap => {
        snap.forEach(storeNames => {
            stores.push(storeNames.key)
        })
        return stores
    })
}
```

and I call it from home like this:

```
let stores = db.getShopNames()
```

I want it to work so if a new store gets added to the real-time database, the variable updates

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of file based scope in JavaScript. The listener will stay active from the moment you call `on('value'`, until you either call `off` on that same location or until you load a new page.

But your `return stores` doesn't do anything meaningful right now. It returns a value from the callback function that nobody will ever see/use.

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, which means you can't return it from a function in the normal way. By the time the return statement runs, the data hasn't loaded yet. That's why you'll usually return a so-called promise, which then resolves when the data has loaded.

In your function that'd be:

```
export function getShopNames() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let userID = auth.currentUser.uid
    let stores = []
    userDB.ref('/users/' + userID + "/stores").once('value', snap => {
        snap.forEach(storeNames => {
            stores.push(storeNames.key)
        })
        resolve(stores);
    }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
    })
}
```

Now you can call this function like this:

```
getShopNames().then((shopnames) => {
  console.log(shopnames);
})
```

---

**Update**: you commented that you also want to handle updates to the shop names, you can't use `once()` and can't use promises (since those only resolve once).

Instead pass in a custom callback, and invoke that every time the shop names change:

```
export function getShopNames(callback) {
    let userID = auth.currentUser.uid
    let stores = []
    userDB.ref('/users/' + userID + "/stores").once('value', snap => {
        snap.forEach(storeNames => {
            stores.push(storeNames.key)
        })
        callback(stores);
    })
}
```

And then call it like:

```
getShopnames(function(shopnames) {
    console.log(shopnames);
});
```

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for the info. However, I was previously using your method with a promise but that only works with a .once. I need to use a .on because more shopnames can be added to the database in real-time, so I need to keep the link open. How can I assign a variable in home.js that connects to an active listener in db.js?